# Replace the specified string to its appearance time using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I want to replace oooo to 1, 2, 3, ..., like a example below:

### From

```
> cat demo.snippet

snippet anova.cca "anova.cca fun"
    anova.cca(
    ,${oooo:object}
    ${oooo:,...}
    ,permutations = ${oooo:how(nperm = 999)}
    ,by = ${oooo:NULL}
    )
endsnippet

snippet adonis "adonis fun"
    adonis(
    ,${oooo:formula}
    ,data = ${oooo:NULL}
    ,permutations = ${oooo:999}
    )
endsnippet

snippet anosim "anosim fun"
    anosim(
    ${oooo:,...}
    ,${oooo:grouping}
    ,permutations = ${oooo:999}
    )
endsnippet
```

### to

```
snippet anova.cca "anova.cca fun"
    anova.cca(
    ,${1:object}
    ${2:,...}
    ,permutations = ${3:how(nperm = 999)}
    ,by = ${4:NULL}
    )
endsnippet

snippet adonis "adonis fun"
    adonis(
    ,${1:formula}
    ,data = ${2:NULL}
    ,permutations = ${3:999}
    )
endsnippet

snippet anosim "anosim fun"
    anosim(
    ${1:,...}
    ,${2:grouping}
    ,permutations = ${3:999}
    )
endsnippet
```

Comment: So you want the counter to start at 1 and to reset for each snippet?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to use sed or awk or perl, could it be possible?

Comment: Perl for sure, awk likely, sed I don't know. I am just not fluent those (too much write only for my taste). Was my assumption that 'oooo' occurs at most once on a line correct?

Answer (score 3):

With python (version 2 or 3):

```
from __future__ import print_function

oooo = None

with open('demo.snippet') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('snippet '):
            oooo = 1
        while 'oooo' in line:
            line = line.replace('oooo', str(oooo), 1)
            oooo += 1
        print(line, end='')
```

This also works if there would be more than one occurrence of `oooo` on one line.

Answer (score 2):

A possible perl solution

```
perl -00 -F/\nendsnippet\n/ -pe '$n=1; s/oooo/$n++/ge' demo.snippet
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `perl`, without slurping whole file in memory:

```
perl -pe 's/oooo/++$i/ge; $i = 0 if /endsnippet/' <file
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following `awk` code, it seems work very well.

```
awk 'BEGIN {x=0} 
     { if ($0~/oooo/) {x++; gsub(/oooo/,x); print $0} 
       else if ($0~/snippet/) {x=0; print $0} 
       else {print $0}}' demo.snippet
```

edit: this can be rewrite as

```
awk 'BEGIN {x=0} 
     /oooo/ {x++; gsub(/oooo/,x); print $0 ; next }  
     /snippet/ {x=0;  }
     {print } ' demo.snippet
```

Comment: That will fail if you have two `oooo` on the same line: both will be replaced by the same number.